# hook_views_pre_execute is not executing

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-hooks

I am trying to modify the query by using the hook_views_pre_execute but I think is not executing at all. Right now my code is the following:

```
function custom_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    echo"hola";
}
```

And its never executing. In the same file I'm using the custom_views_alter_query and is executing perfectly.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Check if your module is enabled and setup correctly

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the caching issue, please clear your drupal cache and try again so that the hook will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Adding output to the view can be accomplished by placing text on $view->attachment_before and $view->attachment_after." This is from Views API. This function will execute just before the db query. Try some debugging, if nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this when facing a similar issue - I was trying to `ksm()` inside the `pre_execute` hook, and it was only firing for one of my views on the page, but not the other (I had 2 Views blocks placed). I realized that an issue with the contextual filter was the issue... Views does a lot of try/catch internally, so you don't always get a fatal "WSOD", but check the watchdog for clues this might be happening - I was getting a "Warning" related to the contextual filter... removing it allowed me to at least see the `ksm()` output and move forward... hopefully this might help someone.